# SQL Server -Succeed insert statement but records did not load

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

On what scenario can merge/insert/update statement complete successfully without error and not load any records to the target table because of some error, locking or other issue?

I am trying to see what scenario my stored procedure will not fail or throw errors but records would not be loaded in database.

Comment: If the statement succeeds, then any records that should have been loaded would be.  Of course, it is easy to have a statement that would affect zero records in the database.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. *"complete successfully without error and not load any records ... because of some error"* If there wasn't an error, how can there be an error?

Comment: It would be better to include your code, and if you're using `MERGE` I think it has some [bugs](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)

Comment: Please give an example of what you are asking, because your description doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

> On what scenario can merge/insert/update statement complete successfully without error and not load any records to the target table

Some possibilities:

- the DML statement succeeded, but affected 0 rows
- it succeeded, but was in a transaction that was subsequently rolled back
- you have INSTEAD OF triggers on the table.

This is assuming you're not looking at the wrong table or the wrong database, which is sometimes easy to do.